# PostgreSQL insert или update

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(id BIGSERIAL, a TEXT NOT NULL, b TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Как сделать уникальными столбцы a и b (чтобы негзя было вставить две записи с одинаковыми a и b: 1, "5", "5" и 2, "5", "5" например)
и когда конфликт при вставке сделать update той записи с которой конфликт?

Comment: добавить уникальный индекс, содержащий эти 2 поля. Использовать insert on conflict

Comment: @Mike можно пример? у меня пишет что не могут в одной таблице много столбцов быть уникальными

Comment: `create unique index table_uniq_ab on table(a, b)`

Comment: @Mike спасибо, работает